# Making operations between items of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming I have `n` arrays. Is there a simple way of doing operations between each items of these arrays ?

Example : 2 arrays

```
arr1 = [true,false,false,true]

arr2 = [false,true,false,true]
```

I'd like to make an `AND` operation :

Expected result :

```
[false,false,false,true]
```

Can you give me some hints for doing this ?

Comment: Use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or a `for` loop? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a proposal with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and for arrays with any length, like `[arr1, arr2, ...]`.

```js
function and(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.map(function (b, i) {
            return a[i] && b;
        });
    });
}

var arr1 = [true, false, false, true],
    arr2 = [false, true, false, true],
    result = and([arr1, arr2]);

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var and = array => array.reduce((r, a) => r.map((b, i) => a[i] && b)),
    arr1 = [true, false, false, true],
    arr2 = [false, true, false, true],
    result = and([arr1, arr2]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, let's put your *n* arrays into an array:

```
var arrs = [
    [...],
    [...]
];
```

Then a very simple implementation using only loops:

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrs[0].length; i++) {
    var value = arrs[0][i];
    for (var j = 1; j < arrs.length; j++) {
        value = value && arrs[j][i];
    }
    results.push(value);
}
```

The `i` counter traverses the first array horizontally, the `j` counter traverses your *n* arrays vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
arr1 = [true, false, false, true]
arr2 = [false, true, false, true];
var op = [];
arr1.forEach(function(item, i) {
  op.push(item && arr2[i]);
});
console.log(op);
```

Comment: What if I have 50 arrays ?

Comment: You can have `n` arrays but both arrays should have identical `length`

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what "*n* arrays" means. How would your code apply if there was also an `arr3`? How would it apply if I didn't know in advance how many `arr*` there are?

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method

```js
var arr1 = [true, false, false, true],
  arr2 = [false, true, false, true];

// put all arrays inside a single array
var arrs = [arr1, arr2];
// set result as initial array values
var res = arrs[0];
// iterate over remaining array
arrs.slice(1).forEach(function(v, i) {
  // iterate over array values and apply logical and operation
  arr1.forEach(function(item, i) {
    res[0] = res[0] && arr2[i];
  });
})
console.log(res);
```

---

Or define  it as a function

```js
var arr1 = [true, true, false, true],
  arr2 = [false, true, false, true],
  arr3 = [false, true, false, false];

function combine(...arrs) {
  // set result as first array
  var res = arrs[0];
  // iterate over remaining array
  arrs.slice(1).forEach(function(v, i) {
    // iterate over array values and apply logical and operation
    arr1.forEach(function(item, i) {
      res[0] = res[0] && arr2[i];
    });
  });
  return res;
}
console.log(combine(arr1, arr2, arr3));
```

Comment: What if I have 50 arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution... You can define the callback to hold your operation and throw it in the inner map functor. The first snippet shows and answer to your question and the second gives an answer in general.

```js
var arrs = [[true,false,false,true,true,true],[false,true,false,true,true,true],[false,true,true,true,true,false]],
  result = arrs.reduce((p,c) => p.map((e,i) => e && c[i]));
console.log(result);
```

```js
var   arrs = [[true,false,false,true,true,true],[false,true,false,true,true,true],[false,true,true,true,true,false]],
crashemall = (ar,cb) => ar.reduce((p,c) => p.map((e,i) => cb(e,c[i]))),
       cb1 = (a,b) => a || b,
       cb2 = (a,b) => !a && b
   result1 = crashemall(arrs,cb1),
   result2 = crashemall(arrs,cb2);
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```